# events action in system dynamics problem using anylogic

Tags: events, anylogic, schedule, systemdynamics

can anyone help me with the function i have to insert in the action?
It's a system dynimcs problem and my goal is to work 8 hours and then stop the production every day. The input flows are ApprovSaggina and ApprovBastoni so I think this flows must be stopped [image]

Thanks a lot

I've tried onChange() but I'm not sure

Comment: Also, pls do this tutorial, it explains such concepts and a ton more: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/system-dynamics/index.html

Comment: i told you in the other question that you need 2 events and a dynamic event defined as a constant connected to all the flows you need to turn off/on

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the inputs to the flows to zero. So for the `ApprovBastoni`, you can use `set_rit(0)`.

If you'd have a variable `rateSaggina` that is used to define the `ApprovSaggina`, you could call `rateSaggina=0.;`

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. So the action field is empty? Event is not useful for my problem?

Comment: use the code I suggest in the event action field